# Does $V=im(T)\oplus ker(T)$ hold if $T$ is an idempotent linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a well known fact for $T$ is a linear transformation. Would it be any different $T$ is idempotent, $T^2=T$?

Comment: Idempotent means $T^2=T$. It will be the same for any $T$.

Comment: What is Ker(T) if T is not linear?

Comment: You say "this is a well known fact for $T$ is a linear transformation". If you assume your idempotent transformation to be linear then of course it should hold for it, too, otherwise you should define the what you mean by kernel of a non-linear transformation -- beware that in that case $\ker(T) := T^{-1}(0)$ would likely not work, because it isn't guaranteed to be a vector subspace of $V$ if $T$ isn't linear.

Answer (score 4):

For $v\in V$, $v=Tv+(v-Tv)\in im(T)+ker(T)$ because $T(v-Tv)=Tv-T^2v=0$ since $T$ is idempotent. The sum is direct because if $Tv\in ker(T)\cap im(T)$, $T^2v=Tv=0$.